# What is the current status of rolling-shutter-free CMOS sensors on the market?

Tags: image-sensors

It is now common to have CMOS pixel matrices inside DSLRs and video cameras. However, when acquiring movies, these sensors suffer from artifacts known as rolling shutter effect, since they are due to the electronic rolling shutter (but surprisingly, CCDs with electronic rolling shutters did not create those artifacts, which gives me hope that there is a hardware solution).

I've read on the web recently (in reports from CMOS lab meetings) that rolling-shutter-free CMOS sensors were now available, and I have also noticed that the "jelly" effect was reduced on recent cameras, but I couldn't find precise information.

Hence, I was wondering if someone knew the current status of global shutter CMOS sensors for the market ? Are they still in the research labs, or embedded in high end devices, coming soon... ?

Answer (score 4):

OK, answering my own question. Sony recently announced a 4K CMOS sensor with an electronic global shutter, see [this blog post](http://image-sensors-world.blogspot.ch/2012/10/sony-cinealta-camera-offers-global.html) and the references inside.

So, the status seems to be: reaching the higher end of the market right now (Nov. 2012), the technology does exist. We still have to wait a few years before seeing these global shutters in lower tiers though.